# accessing ssl web service from the websphere 8.5.5.2

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere

We have an java web application and we need to access a web service which is a https web service. So i add the ssl certificate to Websphere;

SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultKeyStore > Signer Certificates

SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer Certificates

When application trying to access the web service an exception was thrown like this:

```
tr.biznet.msign.service.signature.SignatureException: Mobil signature certificate query is failed. Unknown error.
    at tr.biznet.msign.service.signature.SignatureService.queryMobileSignCertificateRef(SignatureService.java:440)
    at tr.biznet.msign.controller.signature.BsspController.queryMobileSignCertificateRef(BsspController.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:372)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:736)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:360)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at tr.biznet.msign.controller.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:68)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
  Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The following WSDL exception occurred: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: WEBSERVICELINK
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1202)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.(ServiceDelegate.java:218)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:57)
    at com.turkcelltech.mobilesignature.validation.soap.MSSProfileQueryService.(MSSProfileQueryService.java:50)
    at tr.biznet.msign.service.signature.SignatureService.queryMobileSignCertificateRef(SignatureService.java:411)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: WEBSERVICELINK
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:234)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1182)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: WEBSERVICELINK
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:203)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: WEBSERVICELINK
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1479)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:63)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$14.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:974)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getInputStream(WSDL4JWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:189)
    ... 63 more
```

I masked the private web service address (WEBSERVICELINK)
On the other hand I tested the application with weblogic and tomcat. I can access the secure web service.

So i need some help about the websphere. Is there any configuration for this?

Comment: If you get a HTTP 500 there should be some error log entry on server side. From this error log I would not assume that there are any SSL problems.

Comment: BTW, for this scenario you don't add the cert to the key store, only to the trust store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem

IBM Was use own axis framework for web service client. Problem is when you use third part library for web service client, (axis2, jax-ws) client code is generated by third part library. There can be a discrepancy between generated code and was ws library.

Solution

Use local classloader first for your application. (WAS administration console)

Enterprise Applications > "your_app" > Manage Modules > "module_name" > Custom properties

add: com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine = true

Enterprise Applications > "your_app" > Manage Modules > "module_name"

select: "local classloader first (parent last)"

Enterprise Applications > "your_app" > Class loader

tick: Override class reloading settings for Web and EJB modules
tick: Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)
tick: Class loader for each WAR file in application