# JAVA JAX-WS client getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, soap, nullpointerexception, jax-ws

I'm new to web services. Right now i'm trying to consume JAX-WS web service on IBM WebSphere Application Server 7. Sending SOAP message with security header[username, password] parameters. Getting NullPointerException..

Please help me to trace this error.

```
Exception : 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:559)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:497)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy664.getBusinessDetails(Unknown Source)
    at org.acra.businessdetailsclient.GetBusinessDetails_L1Proxy.getBusinessDetails(GetBusinessDetails_L1Proxy.java:131)
    at dao.BE01JNewACRAServicesDAO.getBusinessDetail(BE01JNewACRAServicesDAO.java:47)
    at main.BE01STestACRA.doPost(BE01STestACRA.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.util.XMLFaultUtils.createXMLFault(XMLFaultUtils.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLSpineImpl.getXMLFault(XMLSpineImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.XMLPartBase.getXMLFault(XMLPartBase.java:410)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.MessageImpl.getXMLFault(MessageImpl.java:632)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1004)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:439)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: HiAShoke,Did you get solution for this. I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use third party web service client library? (jaxws or apache cxf)

Maybe problem is websphere use own web service client framework.

[accessing ssl web service from the websphere 8.5.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933819/accessing-ssl-web-service-from-the-websphere-8-5-5-2/25074443#25074443)